# VLookup if Lookup Value Located in Column to the Right of Table Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet set up, and it already contains a lot of data. The A column holds date objects and column B holds numerical values. I want to use Vlookup to find the numerical value and to return the corresponding date value. The problem is that Vlookup searches in the leftmost column of the table array, which is a problem since the column holds dates. This would be easy to do if I was looking up dates, but how can I do it for looking up the numerical value. I understand that swapping the date and numerical column would do it, but I'm looking for a solution that allows me to keep the structure of my spreadsheet intact.

Answer (score 4):

Example

```
date         value
01/01/2010    4
10/02/2011    5
15/03/2011    2


=INDICE(A2:A4;CONFRONTA(5;B2:B4;0))
```

This gives you `10/02/2011`.

These are Italian function names.
English equivalents are `INDEX` and `MATCH`, respectively.

**edit. Update after user's question.**

Let' suppose that your dates are in the range a2:a7 and its values on b2:b7 and that you're looking for the most recent date that has a value of 5:

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=5;$A$2:$A$7))
```

you have to use array formula, so you need to press `ctrl+shift+enter` once you've typed the it.

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine, but I have one thing to add. So from my test, this returns the date once the value is found. However, I can foresee having the same value present in the table with different dates. I believe this would return the first date.

However, in my spreadsheet the dates are ascending (more recent going down) so in case of a duplication of the value, I would like to see returned the most recent date that corresponds with that value. 

So it would be something like return the date if value X is the last value X in that column.

Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Italian excel version uses ";" as parameters separator. Adapt it to your version. :)

Comment: @techman: `VLOOKUP` would also return the first value -- which just confirms that this answer provides exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois. It seems to me that he needs to get the most recent date, so my first answer didn't fit his needs. :)

Comment: Hello again,

I don't want to be a pain because both solutions are very good, but I realized that I need something slightly different.

Basically, the entries in the spreadsheet are inserted via a VB script, and in fact the entry inserted by this script is a date time STRING of the format "mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00". Therefore, unfortunately, the max function won't work since this gets the largest decimal value which corresponds to a specific date.

So what I really need is something to look up some value X and IF it appears more than once return the date time string that is closest to the bottom.

Comment: Hence, I need to make sure that for a given value, I am having returned the corresponding date time STRING with the largest index value (i.e. it is the closest matching one to the bottom --> it is the most recent entry). I think COUNTA will be needed here to find the minimum difference between COUNTA and the index value value of the matching cell. Also, there are no row gaps in the data.

Regards,